# 3 parameter definition for solid modeling

Tags: function-construction

```
Clear["`.*"]
xyz[u_, v_, c_] = { u^2 - v^2 + c^2, u + v - c, Cos[ v - u + c]};
uv = ParametricPlot3D[xyz[u, v, 0], {u, -1, 2}, {v, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
vc = ParametricPlot3D[xyz[0, v, c], {v, -2, 2}, {c, 1, -2}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
cu = ParametricPlot3D[xyz[u, 0, c], {c, 1, -2}, {u, -1, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
Show[{uv, vc, cu}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Is it possible to fill a curvilinear coordinates defined solid by introducing proper function dependencies, using *Mathematica* function defining capability? ( even if it is mathematics but not *Mathematica*? ).

EDIT1:

Can we define domain limits as :

For constant $c,  ( u, umin,umax),\,(v, vmin, vmax)$

For constant $u,  (v, vmin, vmax),\,(c, cmin,cmax )$

For constant $v,  ( c, cmin,cmax),\,(v, vmin, vmax) ?$

Comment: What's the actual definition of the `Region` you want to plot? If you can write it down you can use `RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[...]]`

Comment: RegionPlot3D  forces cartesian coordinates domaiins. Is there no RegionParametricPlot3D?

Comment: What do you mean? Your coordinates are cartesian (unless I don't understand what does `xyz` mean). I repeat the my question: can you please write a closed form formula for the solid you want to plot?

Comment: Also, you have the symmetry `xyz[u,v,c]=xyz[c,v,u]` so that your first and second surfaces are identical

Comment: Can  domains be defined as given in EDIT1? You can help me here for general case. I could program/ define a simple thick/solid spherical segment  using spherical coordinate in ranges for such domains  $ (\theta,\phi, c= r )\,$.

Comment: @yohbs Since it is a parametric plot the independent variables can be delinked and there is no need to be on linked/coupled RegionPlot patches.. You can correct me however if this view is in error Is there a way to proceed?